# Update a layout of a column in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui, upnp

I have a GUI environment to list actions of an UPnP device.
The GUI has on the left side a TreeData and the right side an output console to display the values of the TreeData.
The code of the layout is this:

```py
mainWindowlayout = [
        [
            sg.Menu(menu),
            sg.Text("UPnP console", font=('Roboto', 30))

        ],
        [
            sg.Text(f'Device: {selectedDevice}', key="_DEVICE_", font=('Roboto', 20))
        ],
        [
            sg.Tree(key='-Device Tree-',
                auto_size_columns=True,
                headings=['',],
                select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED,
                data=loadDeviceTree(globals()['device']),
                enable_events=True,
                expand_x=True,
                expand_y=True,
                ),
            sg.Col([
                [sg.Output(s=(120, 50), key='-OUTPUT-')]
                ], key="-DATA COL-")
        ]
    ]
```

[image: GUI console]

My goal is to update the column where the output is to then be able to receive inputs, basically update the layout that is inside the column to a new one.

The code that i'm using is basically useless when it comes to do that, the only useful thing would be the fact that the things i want to convert to a layout are inside a dict.

I've tried to use this lines to do that, with no result:

```py
if event=='-Device Tree-':
    selected_value = values['-Device Tree-'][0] if values['-Device Tree-'] else None
    window['-DATA COL-'].update('')
```

Comment: You can't really update layouts, but you can do things that appears like you've done that.  I'm confused on the details of what you're trying to do. Not sure which "Column" you mean.  If you want to update the Tree, that's not a problem to do.

Comment: I updated the question, the column is the one next to the dataTree

Comment: Ask on the GitHub in an issue where a conversation is easier to have.

Comment: Can you update the content of the Output element, not the layout of the Column element ?

Comment: I'm able to update the column but not the layout, after searching a little bit i found that PySimpleGUI which uses Tkinter doesn't support that kind of stuff, so i just made a new window and so on. Tkinter is great but it has it's own limitations.
Thanks